# How to correctly migrate a JavaFX 8 application to Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx-8

I recently started using Maven (3.x) as I needed the ControlsFX library which is easily available through Maven repository. I installed the m2e plugin for Maven integration and I converted my project to a Maven project (Configure -> Convert to Maven project).

Now, Eclipse (Kepler) warns me at an `@Override` annotation, saying:

```
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
```

But the current code compliance is actually 1.8. In fact, when I use the "1 quick fix available", Eclipse changes these lines:

```
diff --git a/.classpath b/.classpath
index 9c865fb..0a1dadd 100644
--- a/.classpath
+++ b/.classpath
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
-       <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
+       <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
diff --git a/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs b/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
index 29b83c5..0648bb1 100644
--- a/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
+++ b/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 eclipse.preferences.version=1
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.5
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.5
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
@@ -10,4 +10,4 @@ org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations=disabled
-org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
+org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.5
```

My JDK installation is the Oracle's standard:

```
$ java -version                                                              
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

---

### Update

This is the content of my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.tilemup</groupId>
  <artifactId>tilemup</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <jar.final.name>tilemup</jar.final.name>
    <main.class>org.tilemup.Game</main.class>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>${jar.final.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

As you can see, there is `<source>1.8</source>` specified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code or what JDK you have installed. You need to set up the project correctly and specify the source and target Java level. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790957/deprecate-in-java-1-6

Comment: Note that this is simple to do in the actual `.pom` file by configuring the maven compiler plugin ... but I don't use eclipse and am unsure if that's the "right" way to solve the problem when doing so.

Comment: I didn't say that the problem was in my code or in the JDK. In the `pom.xml` file there is `<source>1.8</source>` specified (I will update the question adding more details) but Eclipse seems to ignore it.

Comment: That *should* work. Could be something screwy with eclipse, does it work if you run maven from the command line?

Comment: Yes. I hope this doesn't mean that I should create a jar every time I want to run my application :)

Comment: That's all I got, sorry - hopefully someone who uses eclipse will come along and help.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) doesn't support Java 8. I had to patch it with this procedure:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

Eclipse Luna (4.4) will have native support. Still, I don't understand why Eclipse didn't complain earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, Kepler does not support Java 8 out of the box, however you can go to the eclipse market place (I believe its a submenu of help), in the search box type java 8. The official java 8 kepler plugin will pop up. Install it, and your java 8 problems should dissapear.

I personally use Netbeans for JavaFX projects, but here is a piece of my pom that builds the app using java 8 support

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-createjar</argument>
                            <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                            <argument>-appclass</argument>
                            <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                            <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                            <argument>-outdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                            <argument>-outfile</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>                            
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>  
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </plugin>
```